# Global $.ajaxSetup() call doesn't affect $.ajax() calls in separate functions?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Is there a way to make the scope of $.ajaxSetup() extend to function bodies? I cannot get $.ajaxSetup() to affect the $.ajax() calls within functions. Here's an example:

With the following code, the ajax request sent by function foo() does not include the testHeader specified in ajaxSetup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        testHeader: testValue
    }
});
function foo(theData) {
    $.ajax({
        url: testUrl,
        data: theData,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

However, with the following code, the testHeader does get included in the ajax request sent by foo().

```
function foo(theData) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            testHeader: testValue
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: testUrl,
        data: theData,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

I thought ajaxSetup() is supposed to be global and its scope should extend to function bodies. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: *"I thought ajaxSetup() is supposed to be global and its scope should extend to function bodies"* that is correct. Something else must be happing that isn't included in your question.

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup` should affect all `$.ajax` calls, so as Kevin says, something else must be going on, as it should work.

Comment: possible causes: other calls to `$.ajaxSetup`, and/or multiple versions of jquery

Comment: Thanks. The example code in my question isn't real, but in the real code, I really just have to copy and paste the ajaxSetup() call from outside the function to inside of it, and it works. This is the same page in the same webapp, so I'm not talking about two separate pages with two versions of the code. :\

Comment: if you find yourself calling $.ajaxsetup for multiple different scenarios your should consider option to use 'beforeSend' instead to set headers

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid modifying all the numerous $.ajax() calls in the application. I've found a working solution - see my answer below. Lemme know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think the problem is that $.ajaxSetup() is a function call, not a variable. So when foo() is called, $.ajaxSetup() isn't called by anything yet. Here's how I made it work: put $.ajaxSetup() in a $(function(){}) call:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            testHeader: testValue
        }
    });
});
```

Then the ajax request in foo() will contain the testHeader as desired. Not sure if this is the best solution but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

"Global" may be a misnomer.

$.ajaxSetup will only affect the current jQuery object.  If you load jQuery in another page, it will not be affected.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. Both the call to $.ajaxSetup() and the function foo() are in the same javascript file referenced by the web page. So it's not like I load one page to call ajaxSetup() and then another page to call foo(). 

Let's put my question this way: how do I make sure $.ajaxSetup() is always called before foo() (or any other functions in my script) is called by a form, without calling $.ajaxSetup() inside foo()?

Comment: I've found a solution to this. See my answer. Thanks though!